# Adding an insertion sort, to sort by balances. Also creating a loop for a check digit

Tags: c#

So as of right now, I have multiple accounts made. With account numbers and balances. I want to add an insertion sort, to sort the balances in descending order.

So in short, I need some help sorting by account balance - Here's the code

```
class Program
{
    public class Account
    {
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public double AccountBal { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "ID: " + AccountId + "   Name: " + AccountName + " \tBalance:  " + String.Format("{0:c}", AccountBal);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> actNames = new List<string>
            { "Bill","Laura","John","Joe","Chris","Pete","Sally","Jessica","Paul","Lynsey"};
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int i, tmp, idx;
            int n = actNames.Count;
            double total = 0;
            double actBal = 0;
            double avg = 0;
            List<Account> customer = new List<Account>();
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                idx = rnd.Next(0, actNames.Count);
                Account act = new Account();
                act.AccountName = actNames[idx]; // Account Name
                actNames.RemoveAt(idx);
                tmp = rnd.Next(10000, 99999);
                tmp += tmp * 100 + (tmp / 100000) + (tmp % 100000) / 1000 + tmp;
                act.AccountId = tmp; // Account ID #
                customer.Add(act);
                actBal = rnd.Next(100, 6000);
                act.AccountBal = actBal; // Account Balance
                total += actBal; // sum the account balances in the loop
            }
            foreach (Account aID in customer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aID);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            avg = total / 10; // avg outside the loop
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe average account balance is: {0:C}", avg);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That's great.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Sorry posted, and then edited right away, I am having issues creating a selection sort for this program to sort the accounts in descending order by balance, and would love some help haha

Answer (score 0):

it's Very Easy Using Link

```
YourList.OrderByDescending(Acc=>Acc.Balance);
```